# .htaccess ordering?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

What's the most efficient and logical way to order sections of a .htaccess file?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by ordering sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order depends on what you want to express as the directives are applied in the order that they are found. But if possible, I’ll put sections that change often during development first so I’ll find them fast.

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible I would look at the most recent Apache release and pattern your htaccess layout on the apache.conf file seeing how .htaccess files are essentially an extension of the server configuration.